# Is there any workaround for losing focus on popups?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I like to get rid of invaders by suffocating them in closed rooms. Sometimes this goes wrong and I need to move my crew so they don't die.

But I've lost several of my crewmen because sometimes messages pops up about the enemy is charging its FTL drive or some such when they are selected. After that the focus on the previous selected crew members is lost, and I have to find and select them again. What sometimes is hard because they actually are positioned in a way, I would have to select others as well which had to stay where they are or I have to save my crew one by one. This costs time in an situation where every moment is important, and it starts annoying me because this made me already lose a few well equipped games.

So as the title says:

Is there any workaround for loosing focus of selected crew members in case a informal message pops up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any workaround for loosing focus of selected crew members in case a informal message pops up?

**Yes**. Use *pause*. After each message pause the game instantly using space on your keyboard and recheck every crew member again. While paused you can issue commands and the crew members will follow them when you unpause the game.

Other than that, losing your focus during the game is part of the difficulty and the fun.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this feature '^.^ So I can still select crew, give them orders(?) and even redirect reactor energy while paused?

Comment: @Zaibis Yes. Pausing is literally the most important feature of this game. All actions that can be taken when the game is unpaused can be done when it is - this should have been explained to you during the tutorial. You have to play it like a turn based game - playing it in real time is nearly impossible, as I'm sure you've already discovered

Comment: @Zaibis Yes, you can. I edited my answer to include it.